# How do I get the Twitch-tv Popout chat?

Tags: twitch

I am a streamer at nl.twitch.tv and whenever I see someone streaming, they always have a window of the chat next to their game.

Does anybody know how I can get this popout chat?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about LoL. Are you asking how to do something in LoL or in the Twitch-tv interface?

Comment: Questions about the usage of Twitch should be offtopic on this site.

Comment: Why? It seems like a gaming-specific software, and thus on-topic, to me.

Comment: Voting to leave this question closed as it's not connected to a game. See the [meta] post: [Are questions about Twitch on topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14634/4797)

Answer (score 13):

Click on the little gear icon next to where you would type in a message, and select "Popout".

[image: Example]

Comment: Popup chat (change USER to your username): https://www.twitch.tv/popout/USER/chat